# Thread: Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader for iOS 7.1.x

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, cfnetwork

This crash seems to be happening for iOS 7.1.1 and 7.1.2 with AFNetworking 2.5.3:

Here's the stack trace:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000018ef241d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CFNetwork                      0x0000000182567c30 HTTPConnectionCacheEntry::notifyNextProtocolOfOpenConnection(NetConnection*, unsigned char) + 200
2  CFNetwork                      0x0000000182577274 NetConnection::responseIsComplete(void*) + 256
3  CFNetwork                      0x0000000182577118 HTTPNetStreamInfo::sendStreamIsComplete() + 72
4  CFNetwork                      0x0000000182575df0 HTTPNetStreamInfo::_streamImpl_Read(unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 392
5  CFNetwork                      0x000000018254efd8 CoreStreamBase::_streamInterface_Read(unsigned char*, long) + 184
6  CFNetwork                      0x0000000182575970 HTTPProtocol::bytesAvailable(unsigned char) + 224
7  CFNetwork                      0x0000000182573e40 HTTPProtocol::httpReadStreamEvent(unsigned long) + 596
8  CFNetwork                      0x000000018254d4a4 CoreReadStreamClient::coreStreamEventsAvailable(unsigned long) + 64
9  CFNetwork                      0x000000018262be94 CoreStreamBase::_callClientNow(CoreStreamClient*) + 64
10 CFNetwork                      0x000000018262bed4 ___ZN14CoreStreamBase34_streamSetEventAndScheduleDeliveryEmh_block_invoke + 40
11 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001829095e0 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
12 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182560a1c RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
13 CFNetwork                      0x0000000182560898 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 288
14 CFNetwork                      0x00000001825606d4 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 60
15 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001829cb644 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
16 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001829ca9a0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
17 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001829c8c38 __CFRunLoopRun + 632
18 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182909c20 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
19 Foundation                     0x00000001834fe428 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
20 Foundation                     0x000000018358c40c __NSThread__main__ + 1000
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018f683e1c _pthread_body + 168
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018f683d74 _pthread_body + 138
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018f681554 thread_start + 4
```

Does anyone know what's the root cause for this? Is there a solution for it available?

Comment: `objc_msgSend` in a stack trace means a message was being sent to an object that couldn't receive it, usually because it has been released.  Turn on zombies in your build scheme and see which object was supposed to get the message.  (Also, if there was an exception printed in the debug window, add it to the question.)

Comment: Are you running Fabric or Crashlytics? I am seeing the same kind of crashes coming from this: https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashes-on-ios-7-after-updating-to-3-3-4/54693

Comment: Yes I am running Fabric and Crashlytics. Thanks for the link.